# How to Fetch Mini Layout Fields inside Salesforce Apex Class?

Tags: custom-field, page-layout, search-layout, compact-layout, mini-page-layout

On Mini Layout we have Fields & RelatedList, I want to ask on how we can get/Query the Selected Fields for an Object on Mini Layout Page in the Apex Class?

I am using the following code snippet, is it a right way to do so?

List<Metadata.CustomMetadataValue> values = customMetadataRecord.values;
List<Metadata.Metadata> layouts = Metadata.Operations.retrieve(Metadata.MetadataType.Layout, new List {'PurchaseOrder__c-Purchase Order Layout'});

Metadata.Layout layoutMd = (Metadata.Layout)layouts.get(0);
Metadata.MiniLayout mini_layout = layoutMd.minilayout;

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. You did not attach the screenshot. Additionally, your question is a bit light on detail. I suggest you read [how to ask](/help/how-to-ask) then [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/332710/edit) your question to add more detail.

Comment: Hi. You should edit the question to add this code example (and your screenshot).

Comment: I looked at trying to get the mini layout details last year for a requirement and concluded that it isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

If this is possible for your case, I would advice you to go with an object Field set, which is made for use in APEX:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_fieldsets_describe.htm

[https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000MKkCIAW#:~:text=Hello%20Sandeep%2C-,A%20field%20set%20is%20a%20grouping%20of%20fields.,its%20fields%20and%20render%20them](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000MKkCIAW#:%7E:text=Hello%20Sandeep%2C-,A%20field%20set%20is%20a%20grouping%20of%20fields.,its%20fields%20and%20render%20them).

Please give me feedback if this would help you, if not I would try to give more details.

Comment: I am using the following code snippet, is it a right way to do so? 

List<Metadata.CustomMetadataValue> values = customMetadataRecord.values;
 List<Metadata.Metadata> layouts = Metadata.Operations.retrieve(Metadata.MetadataType.Layout, new List<String> {'PurchaseOrder__c-Purchase Order Layout'});
    
Metadata.Layout layoutMd = (Metadata.Layout)layouts.get(0);  
Metadata.MiniLayout mini_layout = layoutMd.minilayout;